# Finding the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime number and $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has no proper subgroups and find the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$.

I have several questions regarding this problem: $(1)$  To do this I suppose $\mathbb{Z}_p$ have a subgroup H, then we have at least two elements in the set $H$, therefore $x\ast y\in H$ for $x,y\in H$. Given any two elements we get another element in the set, let this last element be $k$; the operation if $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the addition with module $p$, then we have $(x+y)p=k$ which implies $x+y=pk^{-1}$. This gives a divisor of $p$, which contradicts $p$ prime.

But I have no idea how to do $(2)$. I think that these subgroups will be of the form $\{0,k,2k,\dots\}\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{n^p/k}$ with $k$ divisor of $n^p$, but I don't know how to give a more general form.

Comment: I confess I did not understand your proof for the first question. You say $x + y = k$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ implies that $(x+y)p = k$; are you sure this is what you meant to write?

Comment: Lagrange's theorem is really the key here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

(1) Since $p$ is prime then every nonidentity element of  $\mathbb{Z}_p$ generates the group. That is for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ so that $x \neq e$, $\mathbb{Z}_p = \langle x \rangle$. In general in a cyclic group $G=\langle x \rangle$, if $a \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a< ord(x)$ and $gcd(a,ord(x))=1$ then $x^a$ also generates G. Note that $|G|=ord(x)$. Or simply appeal to Lagrange's theorem. If $H$ is subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ then $|H|$ divides $p$. You can then conclude either H is trivial or H is the whole group.

(2) Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. Use Lagrange's and/or Cauchy's theorem to determine what the order of these subgroups could be.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Generally if $d|n$ there is a unique subgroupe $G_d$ of $\Bbb Z_n$ having $d$ as order , that is the cyclic group $$G_d=\left\langle\overline{\frac nd } \right\rangle$$